# Rank of $A=BC$, when ranks of $B,C$ are given.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**[NBHM-PhD Screening test-2015, Algebra(Q 1.7)]**

> Let $B$ be a $5\times3$ matrix and let $C$ be a $3\times5$ matrix, both with real entries. Set $A=BC$. Then what are the possible ranks of $A$ when
>
> (1) both $B$ and $C$ have rank $3$
>
> (2) both $B$ and $C$ have rank $ 2$

I know that $\operatorname{rank}A\leq \min(\operatorname{rank}C,\operatorname{rank}B)$. From this I can say in first case $\operatorname{rank}A\leq 3,$ and in second case $\leq2$. What more we can say about rank of $A$?

also is there any  general method to attack such kind of problems

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sylvester's rank inequality $\operatorname{rank}(BC) \geq \operatorname{rank}(B)+ \operatorname{rank}(C)-n$ when $B$ is $m \times n$ and $C$ is $n \times k$ to conclude that

(i) $\operatorname{rank}(BC) \ge 3+3-3=3 $

(ii) $\operatorname{rank}(BC) \ge 2+2-3=1$

Comment: One can also use that $\operatorname{rank}(BC)\le\min(\operatorname{rank}B,\operatorname{rank}C)$, and conclude that $\operatorname{rank}(BC)=3$.

Answer (score 3):

If both $B$ and $C$ have rank $3$, then $\operatorname{rank}A=3$. In order to see why, note that $C.\mathbb{R}^5=\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore, since $\operatorname{rank}B=3$, $A.\mathbb{R}^5=B.(C.\mathbb{R}^5)=B.\mathbb{R}^3$, which has dimension $3$.

On the other hand, if $\operatorname{rank}B=\operatorname{rank}C=2$, $\operatorname{rank}A$ may be equal to $2$, but it may be smaller, too.

Comment: Sir can you please explain, what is this notation is $C.\mathbb{R}^5=\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @N.Maneesh $C.\mathbb{R}^5=\{C.v\,|\,v\in\mathbb{R}^5\}$.